# sed command adds extra characters in the file

Tags: bash, sed

I have a text file that contains a list of names `file.txt` and then i am looping through this file and i want to create a new text file by adding these names to the new text file and append some other data to the new text file. The problem is the `sed` command works fine but then it appends some duplicate characters in some cases.
my file `file.txt` is

```
cat file.txt
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
ddddd
eeeee
fffff
```

my `sed` command is

```
while IFS="" read -r name
do
    sed -i "s/${name}/uniquemember: ID=${name},ou=people,ou=names,dc=xxxx,dc=xxx/g" file.txt
done<"file.txt"
```

now the resultant file is

```
uniquemember: ID=aaaaa,ou=people,ou=names,dc=xxx,dc=xxx
uniquemember: ID=bbbbb,ou=people,ou=names,dc=motorola,dc=xxx
uniquemember: ID=ccccc,ou=people,ou=names,dc=motorola,dc=xxx
uniquemember: ID=uniquemember: ID=ddddd,ou=people,ou=names,dc=xxx,dc=xxxg,ou=people,ou=names,dc=xxx,dc=xxx
uniquemember: ID=eeeee,ou=people,ou=names,dc=xxx,dc=xxx
```

i am not sure why so many extra characters are adding in this line `uniquemember: ID=uniquemember: ID=ddddd,ou=people,ou=names,dc=xxx,dc=xxxg,ou=people,ou=names,dc=xxx,dc=xxx`

How can i fix this?

Comment: What's output of `cat -A file.txt`

Comment: You are reading the file `file.txt` and manipulating it at the same time.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your actual data, but I suspect you have a name that's a substring of another name, e.g. "sam" and "samuel". In that case, when you do the replacement on "samuel" it works as expected, but replacing "sam" also replaces *part of* the "samuel" entry, resulting in chaos. Solution: don't apply changes that only apply to one line to the entire file; process it line-by-line, making relevant changes to each line as you go (as @Ass3mbler's solution does directly in `sed`).

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you use a simpler command like this?

```
sed "s/\(.*\)/uniquemember: ID=\1,ou=people,ou=names,dc=xxxx,dc=xxx/g" file.txt
```

**output:**

```
uniquemember: ID=aaaaa,ou=people,ou=names,dc=xxxx,dc=xxx
uniquemember: ID=bbbbb,ou=people,ou=names,dc=xxxx,dc=xxx
uniquemember: ID=ccccc,ou=people,ou=names,dc=xxxx,dc=xxx
uniquemember: ID=ddddd,ou=people,ou=names,dc=xxxx,dc=xxx
uniquemember: ID=eeeee,ou=people,ou=names,dc=xxxx,dc=xxx
uniquemember: ID=fffff,ou=people,ou=names,dc=xxxx,dc=xxx
```